# asp.net core Login function error "not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller

Hello guys I am trying to make this Login function. I am getting an error on the Login() method, `not all code paths return a value`.

My action method is given below:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel Input)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    logger.LogInformation("User logged in."); 
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
                }
            }
        }
```

I have added 2 return statements. I can't find my mistake. Can you help me fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens when `ModelState` is anything except `IsValid`? You're welcome.

Comment: HAHA. Must have lost my mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two `if` statements. One of the statements has an else also. So in total there are three possible execution paths. If the first `if` statement isn't true then it entirely skips the next one which has all the return paths. Hence it gets to the bottom of the function without a return value.

Try this instead.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel Input)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                logger.LogInformation("User logged in."); 

                // Login is successful here, so we return now and the execution stops, meaning the bottom code never runs.
                return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
            }
        }

        // If we get to this line, either the MoxelState isn't valid or the login failed.
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First if statement check the model state validation but you are totally ignoring the falling of validation and missing a return for this function. you should add return view() or whatever suits your situation after your first modelstate.isvalid if statement. i added as comment.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel Input)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    logger.LogInformation("User logged in."); 
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
                }
            }
//you must return something here
//return View(Input);
        }
```